# Flutter Multilanguage Application

Tags: flutter, localization, multilingual, flutter-localizations

Hi I have used [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package to add other languages to my application. but I want to know how we can translate api calls data. for example, imagine we have an e-commerce application and we want to translate products titles and other information to the selected locale. What should we do and how we can do that in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not using any packages for localization. The documentation is already detailed enough, and the apis are very simple- You really don't have to do much another then add a few lines, and the translation files.

Those products would have to be already localized so you would have an endpoint for example with `/en/` for english and `/fr/` for french etc. And in the app you would just check the localization and use the right endpoint. You don't hard code translations in your .arb files or anything like that for dynamically changing items.